# Google Apps for Work Custom URL

Tags: google-apps

Using Google Apps for Work, there is a possibility to define custom URLs for Google Services (such as GMail, Google Calendar, ...), e.g. *calendar.mydomain.com*. These URLs redirect you to the respective Google Service and its usual domain URL, in this case *https://www.google.com/calendar/b/2/render*.

I was just curious whether there was a scenario, in which opening calendar.mydomain.com would not resolve in a redirect to http://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/mydomain.com". As a result you would still see the calendar.mydomain.com instead of the google calendar URL in your browser address bar. The common case seems to be, that invoking calendar.mydomain.com results in a 302 HTTP status code and you get redirected to the Google service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected and supported behavior provided by Google as detailed [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53340). I don't believe it'll be possible to prevent the redirection as you've detailed it.